# Need help understanding Linux kernel's BIOS interrupt calls

Tags: c, assembly, linux-kernel

I am studying Linux source code to find out how it gets a memory map. I think it starts by calling [detect_memory()](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.13.5/arch/x86/boot/main.c#L158) which is defined [here](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.13.5/arch/x86/boot/memory.c#L122). This function calls `detect_memory_e820()` which is defined in the same file. `detect_memory_e820()` at line 48 calls `intcall` which is defined like this:

```
    .code16gcc
    .text
    .globl  intcall
    .type   intcall, @function
intcall:
    /* Self-modify the INT instruction.  Ugly, but works. */
    cmpb    %al, 3f
    je  1f
    movb    %al, 3f
    jmp 1f      /* Synchronize pipeline */
1:
    /* Save state */
    pushfl
    pushw   %fs
    pushw   %gs
    pushal

    /* Copy input state to stack frame */
    subw    $44, %sp
    movw    %dx, %si
    movw    %sp, %di
    movw    $11, %cx
    rep; movsd

    /* Pop full state from the stack */
    popal
    popw    %gs
    popw    %fs
    popw    %es
    popw    %ds
    popfl

    /* Actual INT */
    .byte   0xcd        /* INT opcode */
3:  .byte   0

    /* Push full state to the stack */
    pushfl
    pushw   %ds
    pushw   %es
    pushw   %fs
    pushw   %gs
    pushal

    /* Re-establish C environment invariants */
    cld
    movzwl  %sp, %esp
    movw    %cs, %ax
    movw    %ax, %ds
    movw    %ax, %es

    /* Copy output state from stack frame */
    movw    68(%esp), %di   /* Original %cx == 3rd argument */
    andw    %di, %di
    jz  4f
    movw    %sp, %si
    movw    $11, %cx
    rep; movsd
4:  addw    $44, %sp

    /* Restore state and return */
    popal
    popw    %gs
    popw    %fs
    popfl
    retl
    .size   intcall, .-intcall
```

My problem is that I cannot figure out what is the value of dx register at this point: `movw    %dx, %si` and from where it comes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that the [makefile](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.13.5/arch/x86/boot/Makefile#L59) specifies `-mregparm=3` for the compilation of 16 bit C code. This instructs the compiler to put the first 3 arguments into the registers `eax`, `edx` and `ecx` if possible. So the value of `dx` is going to be the second argument, `&iregs`. Also notice the comment further down that confirms this: `/* Original %cx == 3rd argument */`

I find it kind of funny that you had no problem right at the start, about how `al` gets the value of the interrupt number :)